# Generically encapsulate action/function with class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to provide encapsulation of actions/methods generically. I think this should be possible in C# but I'm not able to produce it so it compiles...

The following briefly demonstrates what I want. Is this possible somehow, perhaps by generalizing the class?

Required is:

- I want to execute the function/action (see method type) and 'do something' when an error occurs
- I want to return the value of the function **if** the method is a function (otherwise return `void` if possible)
- I want to 'do something' if the return type of the function is a `boolean` and the value is `false`.

  ```
  public class Encapsulator {
      private Action _action;
      private Func<T> _function;
      private MethodType _type; //Action || Function

      public Encapsulator(Action action) {
          this._action = action;
          this._type = MethodType.Action;
      }
      public Encapsulator(Func<T> func) { //This is not accepted
          this._function = func;
          this._type = MethodType.Function;        
      }

      public void Execute() {
          try {
              this._action();
          }
          catch(Exception ex) {
              //do something
              throw;
          }
      }

      public T Execute<T>() {
          try {
              var r = this._function();

              if(typeof(r) == bool) {
                  if(!r)
                    //do something
              }

              return r;

          } catch(Exception ex) {
              //do something
              throw;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Approach: The action Encapsulator will now return a dummy result (always true).

```
public class Encapsulator
{
    public static Encapsulator<bool> CreateEncapsulator(Action action)
    {
        return new Encapsulator<bool>(() =>
            {
                action();
                return true;
            });
    }

    public static Encapsulator<T> CreateEncapsulator<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        return new Encapsulator<T>(func);
    }
}

public class Encapsulator<T>
{
    private Func<T> _function;

    internal Encapsulator(Func<T> func)
    {
        this._function = func;
    }

    public T Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            object res = this._function();
            Nullable<bool> bres = res as Nullable<bool>;

            if (bres.HasValue)
            {
                if (!bres.Value)
                    Console.WriteLine("NOT TRUE!");
                //do something
            }

            return (T)res;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the code:

```
var withDummyReturn = Encapsulator.CreateEncapsulator(() => Console.WriteLine("Great"));
withDummyReturn.Execute();
var withReturn = Encapsulator.CreateEncapsulator<bool>(() => true);
bool res = withReturn.Execute();
```

Comment: This looks alright. Instantiating for `Func<T>` with type argument works: `var x = new Encapsulator<bool>(f);`. But how do I instantiate with the `Action` parameter without a type argument in the class? `var y = new Encapsulator(a);` doesn't work because it expects a type argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your second constructor won't compile because their are no generics applied to the type at the higher level:

```
public Encapsulator<T>
{  
    public Encapsulator(Func<T> func)
    { 
        this._function = func;
        this._type = MethodType.Function;  
    }      
}
```

Instead of just introducing new things within the parameters of a method, essentially, we need to specify that those things are 'available' for utilisation in the definitions. So, for instance, if you were trying to add a specific generic method, you could apply it as you have done, but would instead need to do (something which you demonstrate with the `Execute` method):

```
public void MyGenericMethod<T>(Func<T> func)
{ 

}
```

Noting the *first* `T`, we're specifying the existence of `T`, as such.

There are possibly more issues at hand with your code here, but I believe, on first glance, this to be the crux of the problems you're having.

As for returning variable types, the best you might hope for is returning a plain old `object`. Or, making use of the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type, however, I wouldn't have thought this would be the way to go and wouldn't recommend it; you can't flip return type from an actual type to a void, though.

Comment: But what needs to be provided as type argument for the `Action` scenario when there is no return value..?